# dplyr: create new column with values from other specified columns

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I have a tibble:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

(
  data <- tibble(
    a = 1:3,
    b = 4:6,
    mycol = c('a', 'b', 'a')
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b mycol
#>   <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1     1     4 a    
#> 2     2     5 b    
#> 3     3     6 a
```

Using `dplyr::mutate` I'd like to create a new column called `value` which uses a value from either column `a` or `b`, depending on which column name is specified in the `mycol` column.

```r
(
  desired <- tibble(
    a = 1:3,
    b = 4:6,
    mycol = c('a', 'b', 'a'),
    value = c(1, 5, 3)
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       a     b mycol value
#>   <int> <int> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1     4 a         1
#> 2     2     5 b         5
#> 3     3     6 a         3
```

Here we're just using the values from column `a` all the time.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(value = a)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       a     b mycol value
#>   <int> <int> <chr> <int>
#> 1     1     4 a         1
#> 2     2     5 b         2
#> 3     3     6 a         3
```

Here we're just assigning the values of `mycol` to the new column rather than getting the values from the appropriate column.

```r
data %>%
  mutate(value = mycol)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>       a     b mycol value
#>   <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1     4 a     a    
#> 2     2     5 b     b    
#> 3     3     6 a     a
```

I've tried various combinations of `!!`, `quo()`, etc. but I don't fully understand what's going on under the hood in terms of NSE.

@Jaap has marked this as a duplicate but I'd still like to see a dplyr/tidyverse approach using NSE rather than using base R if possible.

Comment: @Jaap I'd like to see a dplyr/tidyverse approach using NSE if possible, rather than using base R. I've amended the question to reflect this. Would you be able to remove the duplicate status?

Comment: At the moment I'm not going to do that as there is a tidyverse approach in the linked Q&A. Moreover, you said: *"I've tried various combinations of `!!`, `quo()`"*, but you fail to specify those attempts. See also the Q&A on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
df %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(mycol == "a", a, b))
#output
# A tibble: 3 x 4
      a     b mycol value
  <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1     1     4 a         1
2     2     5 b         5
3     3     6 a         3
```

and here is a more general way in base R

```
df$value <- diag(as.matrix(df[,df$mycol]))
```

more complex example:

```
df <- tibble(
    a = 1:4,
    b = 4:7,
    c = 5:8,
    mycol = c('a', 'b', 'a', "c"))

df$value <- diag(as.matrix(df[,df$mycol]))
#output
# A tibble: 4 x 5
      a     b     c mycol value
  <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int>
1     1     4     5 a         1
2     2     5     6 b         5
3     3     6     7 a         3
4     4     7     8 c         8
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just a simple example but I'd like to use the same method for a larger number of columns without specifying them manually. Is there a more automatic solution?

Comment: @Greg I have added a more general base R approach.

Comment: Thanks @missuse. It would still be great to see a tidyverse approach using NSE if possible but I've upvoted your answer. I've also amended the question to make this clearer.